# Multiple databases through a single connection MongoDB, GridFS

Tags: mongodb

I want to use GridFS in your project. As the main database using mongodb.

My application can do only one connection to the database (such conditions).

Can I make calls to other databases using the primary as a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I had the same issue. I use the db.getSiblingDB('yourdb') command in my scripts to make many calls to various databases.

This is documented further at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getSiblingDB/ .